# FileDialog not working in Access 2016

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am using FileDialog code for importing Excel table(s) into Access 2013-32 bit that works exactly like I want.  When I use the code in Access 2016 I get an error in code that says "Can't find project of library".  I have checked my references and they appear to be the same.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Command2_Click()
Dim JobName As String 
Dim f As FileDialog
Dim tblImport As String
Dim varfile As Variant
Dim MyJobs As DAO.Recordset

JobName = lbl1.value


DoCmd.Close


Set f = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With f
.Title = "Choose Excel File(s) to Import"
.Filters.Clear
.Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsx"
.AllowMultiSelect = True


If f.Show = True Then

For Each varfile In .SelectedItems
    Msgbox "IMPORTING: " & varfile
    tblImport = varfile
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, 10, "Parts", tblImport, True
Next varfile


'Add Job Name to Parts Table
TempVars("jobName") = JobName
DoCmd.OpenQuery "Update Job Name"

'Add Job Name to Jobs Table
Set MyJobs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Jobs")
MyJobs.AddNew
MyJobs![JobName] = JobName
MyJobs.Update


Set f = Nothing

Else

Msgbox "You Cancelled."

End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What happens if you uncheck the reference to the Microsoft Office Library and make these 2 changes to your code? `Dim f As Object` and `Application.FileDialog(3)`

Comment: @HansUp that did it!  How will not referencing the Microsoft Office Library affect other applications or functions?

Comment: I suggest you make sure `Option Explicit` is included in the Declarations sections of all your code modules, and then run Debug->Compile from the VB Editor's main menu.  If removing the reference to the Microsoft Office Library has created any problems in your application, Access will show them to you as compile errors.